# Google Chrome extension add a header to every webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if it is possible to add a nonchanging header to every webpage you go to. I know you can do infobars but as it is still experimental I would like to avoid using it if possible. The header would contain a title I put in along with some buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You need to do it in a way that you minimally modify the dom structure. If you just prepend to body you could break code that finds elements relative to body.
Try instread something like changing body top margin then appending a div on absolute position 0,0. Since its at the end of the dom it shouldnt affect tab order or code relying on structure.

Comment: Tbh i havent tried it so let me know if any webpage breaks.